# Scalar function used in calculated column, what's the cleanest way to update the function?

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, functions

I want to update a scalar function in our database.  This function is used for several calculated columns in a key table so I get a dependency error if I try to update it.  I can explicitly remove the columns, update the function and re-add the columns but, without a lot of extra fannying about, that will change column orders and might have other unintended consequences.  I wondered if there was a cleaner way of doing it?

Comment: I resolved this only partially by creating dummy functions calling real ones. Of course, if signature changes, then it is all over again.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think there's any "magic" or "cleaner" way of doing this. If you need to modify the function - you'll need to drop the columns, modify the function, and re-add all columns. No way around this.

Comment: @marc_s Well it's worth a shot, lots of smart people around here :)

Comment: Agree with the above comments. Thought there might have been scope for SYNONYMs to offer some help here (reference a SYNONYM in the computed column) - but you can't ALTER a synonym once created to "redirect" it to another object.

Comment: Still nowhere near as painful as updating the definition of a CLR UDT (even when the change is just a tweak to a method and doesn't affect the storage representation at all)

Comment: Any chance you could post the function?

Comment: @Mack I'm not sure what difference it makes, it'd be the same problem for any function

Comment: @Nikola Markovinović IMO your suggestion is very likely to seriously slow down the performance.

Answer (score 2):

This may be more work but it should get (approximately) what you are after:

1 - Create a new table that has just your PK from the main table and the updated function.

2 - Drop your old column

3 - Rename your old table to something like `TableName_Base`

4 - Create a `VIEW` that joins your main table to your lookup table, with the fields in the order that you want to see them.  Name the view whatever your original table name was.

This will potentially create some issues with `INSERTS` and `UPDATES` though since you'll be accessing via a view.  To deal with that you can either insert into the table directly, bypassing the view.

Comment: That sounds like more work and the same level of risk as removing and re-adding the columns.

Comment: @robertc It'll be less disruptive if this is a high transaction environment, but yes it's still pretty messy.